# Why is my script saying '(' === ')' is true?

Tags: javascript

I was doing [this kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/51f2d1cafc9c0f745c00037d) on codewars. The question wants the function to return true if the first argument (string) passed in ends with the 2nd argument (also a string). So I wrote my function and everything worked just fine until it compares `':-)'` with `':-('` and returns true.

What is wrong? I'm so confident that my code should work that I don't even know what to search for.

```js
function solution(str, ending){
  if (!ending) return true; // if ending is a empty string return true (the question wants that)
  let ok;
  const strArr = str.split(''), endingArr = ending.split('');
  for (let i = 0; i < endingArr.length; i++) strArr.reverse()[i] === endingArr.reverse()[i] ? ok = true : ok = false;
  return ok;
}

console.log(solution(":-)",":-("));
```

Comment: why not use the String.endsWith function to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure what your stating is true?

Comment: One-liner are terrible to read and understand. Do yourself a favor and make use of proper indentation, blocks, intermediate results/variables, ... Let specialized tools do the minimization (if necessary).

Comment: There are several problems. First, "!ending" des not mean that "ending is an empty string" (it could bé undefined, 0, false, etc). Further more, your code will return true even if only the last loop itération is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer explains many of the mistakes you've made. I wanted to point out just how much you've over-thought your solution.

```js
function solution(str, ending){
  if (ending === "") return true; // if ending is a empty string return true (the question wants that)
  return str.endsWith(ending);
}

console.log(solution(":-)",":-("));
console.log(solution("foo",""));
console.log(solution("foo","bar"));
console.log(solution("foobar","bar"));
```

Even my solution above is overengineered, `str.endsWith("")` always returns true. So this can be simplified further.

```js
function solution(str, ending){
  return str.endsWith(ending);
}

console.log(solution(":-)",":-("));
console.log(solution("foo",""));
console.log(solution("foo","bar"));
console.log(solution("foobar","bar"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is a misunderstanding of what `reverse()` does. It does not return a reversed copy of the old array, it reverses the existing array and returns that same array. As a result, you keep reversing the arrays back and forth every iteration of the loop, causing some elements to be skipped and some to be checked twice.

[Array.prototype.reverse() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

Edit:

As pointed out by others in the comments, both to the question and this answer, there are in fact multiple problems.

`reverse()` aside, the loop always sets `ok` to the result of the last comparison, making the function ignore all previous results.

The easier way to implement this is to remove `ok` altogether. Instead, return `false` as soon as a mismatch is detected. If the function runs long enough to exit the loop, it means no mismatch was detected and `true` can be returned.

Edit 2:

Just as a friendly suggestion:

While both `reverse()` and `ok` are real issues with the code, I only noticed the first one the first time around due to the formatting of the code. The `ok` problem was off-screen due to the line being too long. As such, once I spotted the `reverse()` issue, I assumed that was it and didn't bother scrolling sideways to see the rest of the code.

I am not going to demand that you write *your own* code in a certain way, but if you format it properly, it allows *others* to read it more easily. In essence, you help us to more easily help you.

For instance, this line:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < endingArr.length; i++) strArr.reverse()[i] === endingArr.reverse()[i] ? ok = true : ok = false;
```

...would have been significantly easier to read as...

```js
for (let i = 0; i < endingArr.length; i++) {
  if(strArr.reverse()[i] === endingArr.reverse()[i])
    ok = true;
  else
    ok = false;
}
```

...or some variation thereof. Here, the problem is significantly more visible and obvious.

Comment: OP is also reassigning `ok` each iteration, only returning the last value.

Comment: Thanks!!! I've read the mdn page but I'm really bad at comprehending the stuff I read.